# Ruby FileUtils.mkpath behaves differently on different environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filesystems

I have a rails app that contains a simple piece of code to create a directory if one does not exist.

```
FileUtils.mkpath(self.webapp_dir) unless File.exists?(self.webapp_dir)
```

This behaves as expected on my development workstation (OS X 10.9), but I'm getting errors when deployed to other environments (Red Hat 4.4.6-3).

In my rails console, I ran the following:

```
FileUtils.mkpath('/path/to/my/project/public/web_apps/1')
```

Note that on first run, 'public/web_apps/' exists, but '1' does not. This succeeds. I can run it again with the whole path already existing, and it succeeds without error every time.

Now, I try to run the same code in the rails console in the production environment. Again, 'public/web_apps/' already exists, but '1' does not.  In this case I get an error.

```
FileUtils.mkpath('/path/to/my/project/public/web_apps/1')
--> Errno::EEXIST: File exists - /path/to/my/project/public/web_apps
```

Does anyone know why this behaves differently between the two machines, and what I can do about it?  I suppose I could go through and check each directory in the path and create it only if it doesn't exist, but that's what I would have already expected mkpath to do.

I've found other differences between how other functions that interact with the file system behave (like how File.size does not immediately report the correct value after a file write unless you open it first).  I haven't been able to find any mention of these differences in behavior in any documentation or other SO posts though, and I seem to keep stumbling upon them which is getting a little frustrating now.  Is this a known thing, and how do other apps account for this?

Comment: Is the Ruby version and patch number exactly the same in two boxes?

Comment: What version of Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually all due to a broken sym link =(.

So web_apps was actually a sym link to a shared directory that did not exist on our servers.  On my dev machine it did exist. This was not horribly obvious due to the "File exists" error.

Our deployment scripts were building the sym links without first checking if that directory actually existed.  Bah.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a permission issue, the directories are created if they DON'T exist, otherwise you don't get any errors.

Look at the owner of `'/path/to/my/project/public/web_apps/'`